# PHP email are not sending email

Tags: php, html

I am doing code to let the user after he write his mail the website will send for him code to verify his email. But the code are not give me any error also are not sending email to me.

**Body**

```
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 70px;">
          <form action="createaccountPageStepTwo.php">
            <div class="formcreate bg-light bg-gradient shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded col-8">
                <div class="position-relative m-4">
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 1px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria- 
                       valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute top-0 start-0 translate-middle 
                     btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-pill" style="width: 2rem; 
                     height:2rem;">1</button>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle 
                     btn btn-sm btn-secondary rounded-pill" style="width: 2rem; 
                     height:2rem;">2</button>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate- 
                    middle btn btn-sm btn-secondary rounded-pill" style="width: 2rem; 
                    height:2rem;">3</button>
                  </div>
                <p id="signText"> Signup Form</p>
                <div class="row g-3">
                    <div class="col">
                      <input name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First 
                       name" aria-label="First name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <input name="lastName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last 
                       name" aria-label="Last name" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row g-3">
                    <div class="col">
                      <input name="password"id="password" type="password" class="form-control 
                      passwordPov" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <input name="retypePassword" id="retypePassword" type="password" 
                      class="form-control passwordPov" placeholder="Retype Password" aria- 
                      label="RetypePassword" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label"></label>
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" 
                    id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone 
                    else.
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success buttonPos">Next</button>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**php**

```
        <?php
        
            if(isset($_POST['email']))
            {
                $headers = "From: exampe <exaple@example.com>\r\n";
                $to_visitor = $_POST["email"];
                $common_data = $_POST["Welcome to example website verfy code are ( 0000 )"];
                mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $common_data, $headers);
            } 
            
        ?>
```

So what I want that when the user press next the website will send code to the user email and website will take user email through `email input`

I hope my question are clear

Comment: Remove the `$_POST` from your `common_data` variable. You don't have an index named `Welcome to example website verfy code are ( 0000 )`....Although the real issue is `<form action="createaccountPageStepTwo.php">` which is a `GET` not `POST` because you have not `method` defined. Meaning `if(isset($_POST['email']))` is never met and no PHP is executed.

Comment: so can you correct my code please if you can

Comment: I told you the things that need to be fixed.